# Apache Camel - Simple HTTPS Google Places Call - Difference between Spring DSL and Java DSL for Camel-http component ?

Tags: spring, tomcat7, apache-camel, google-places-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Places API using Apache Camel (2.10-SNAPSHOT) and Spring (3.0.7.RELEASE) with Tomcat (7.0.26) as my web conainer server.

When I declare the route in a Spring config xml (see below) I can see the correct output response on my Tomcat logs.

```
<route id="google-places-route">
        <from uri="direct:start" />
        <to uri="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.446788,-79.950559&amp;radius=500&amp;types=food&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=my-google-api-key" />
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </split>        
</route>
```

Please note the camel scheme used here is https and NOT http.

Now, I'm trying to do the same by defining my route in a Java class that extends `RouterBuilder`

`public class GooglePlacesRoute extends RouteBuilder {`

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:start").process(new MyCustomProcessor()).to("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.446788,-79.950559&amp;radius=500&amp;types=food&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=my-google-api-key").to("stream:out");
}
```

}

---

class MyCustomProcessor implements Processor {

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
        Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();


    inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "GET");
    exchange.getIn().setBody("", String.class);

}
```

}

My Camel route is deployed and started correctly. However, when I invoked it I don't get the expected output. I get the following response from Google's servers.

`{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}`

I'm assuming that I don't have to do anything special in my Java DSL to handle HTTPS (instead of HTTP). Is this assumption correct ?

What am I missing here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `&` instead of `&amp;` in your request.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.446788,-79.950559&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=my-google-api-key
```